# Using replace_na for multiple data subsets

Tags: r, replace, subset

I'm trying to replace the NAs in multiple column variables with randomly generated values from each student_id's subset row data:
[data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Teo.png)

so for student 3, systolic needs two NAs replaced. I used the min and max values for each variable within the student 3 subset to generate random values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
dplyr::filter(exercise, student_id == "3") %>% replace_na(list(systolic= round(sample(runif(1000, 125,130),2),0), 
diastolic =round(sample(runif(1000, 85,85),3),0), heart_rate= round(sample(runif(1000, 79,86),2),0), 
phys_score = round(sample(runif(1000, 8,9),2),0)
```

However it works only when **one NA** needs replacing: [successfully replaced systolic NA values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXNE3.png). When I try to replace more than one NAs, this error comes up.

```
Error: Replacement for `systolic` is length 2, not length 1
```

Is there a way to fix this? I tried converting the column variables to data frames instead of the vectors they are now, but it only returned the original data without any replacement changes.

Are there any simpler ways to this? Any suggestions/comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example using `dput` instead of images.  I think you need to create the `systolic`, `diastolic`, `heart_rate` etc. within `mutate` and then do the `replace_na` i.e. `exercise %>% filter(student_id =="3") %>% mutate(systolic = round(sample(runif(1000, 125, 130), 2), 0), ..`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that makes things a little more automated but may be unnecessarily complex.

Generated some grouped missing data from the mtcars dataset

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

## Generate some missing data with a subset of car make
mtcars_miss <- mtcars %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "car") %>%
  select(car) %>% 
  separate(car, c("make", "name"), " ") %>% 
  bind_cols(mtcars[, -1] %>%   
              map_df(~.[sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), 
                               size = length(.), replace = TRUE)])) %>% 
  filter(make %in% c("Mazda", "Hornet", "Merc"))
```

Function to replace na values from a given variable by sampling within the min and max and depending on some group (here make).

```
replace_na_sample <- function(df_miss, var, group = "make") {

  var <- enquo(var)

  df_miss %>% 
    group_by(.dots = group) %>% 
    mutate(replace_var := round(runif(n(), min(!!var, na.rm = T),
                                      max(!!var, na.rm = T)), 0)) %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate_at(.vars = vars(!!var),
              .funs = funs(replace_na(., replace_var))) %>% 
    select(-replace_var) %>% 
    ungroup

}
```

Example replacing several missing values in multiple columns.

```
mtcars_replaced <- mtcars_miss  %>% 
  replace_na_sample(cyl, group = "make") %>% 
  replace_na_sample(disp, group = "make") %>%
  replace_na_sample(hp, group = "make")
```